# foreach() in Model Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good Day All!

I am wondering why is that the `foreach() argument` not working in this code:

```
if ($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE) {
    $data = $this->input->post('pTableData');
    $tableData = json_decode($data);

    if (isset($tableData)) {
        foreach ($tableData as $get) {
            $this->insert_activity($id, $get);
        }
    } else {
        echo "NULL";
    }
}
```

I just to know if `var $tableData isset` or `has value` it will proceed to the another `function inside the model`.

Comment: have you tried dumping $tableData to see what it contains?

Comment: Yes as suggested.First try printing all the variables you are using in your code on every step. `e.g. print_r("<pre>");print_r($tableData);`
And check if the variable is an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE)
    {
        $data = $this->input->post('pTableData');
        $tableData = json_decode($data, true); // add a second argument as true to force json_decode to parse it to array
        if (isset($tableData) && is_array($tableData)) // check if the $tableData received is actually an array
            {
                foreach ($tableData as $get) 
                    {
                        $this->insert_activity($id, $get);
                    }
            }
                else
                    {
                        echo "NULL";
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isset($tableData) && is_array( $tableData ) && count( $tableData ) > 0 ){ //is array and has elements
    //your process here with the array
}else{
    // here you proceed to another function like you asked
}
```